# Where to put an Ember view for each response from a websocket

Tags: ember.js

I have the following ember controller that is going to wait for json objects to be passed from a websocket server via the onmessage handler:

```
Lead.Controllers.ParsingController = Ember.Object.extend
  start_parsing: (url_search) ->
    socket = new Lead.WebSocket("ws://#{document.domain}:61615")

    socket.onopen = (evt) ->
      socket.send url_search.search_url

    socket.onmessage = (evt) ->
      Lead.leads_controller.addLead evt.data
```

My LeadsController currently looks like this:

```
Lead.Controllers.Leads = Ember.Object.extend

  addLead: (lead) ->    
    @view = Ember.View.create
      controller: @
      #etc.
```

My questions are these:

1. Am I right not to use an ArrayController because they are only to be used for collections?  Sorry for the obvious question but I just want to check.
2. If I create a new view, everytime the addLead method is called, will I need to keep a reference to each view in an internal array and iterate over the array calling dispose on each child view when I am disposing of the main view?
3. Would I be better off creating a separate controller for each child view that is appended?  I am guessing no but would like to check.

Any help or guidance on these questions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not going to answer your specific questions, but rather suggest an alternate implementation that I think would be more idiomatic Ember and be simpler.

It's hard to tell what your broader view layer looks like, but I based on my guess at your problem domain, I would think that you would have a `#each` helper or `CollectionView` that is databound to a `leadsController` which subclasses `ArrayProxy`. When the json comes in from the websocket, call `pushObject` on the `leadsController`. Bindings will automatically update and render the new lead in the view output.

If I misunderstood the app's functionality, please do clarify.